# Transposing a column of data in SQL

Tags: sql

In SQL my data output is

| Agreement ID | ProductStatus |
| --- | --- |
| 125 | A |
| 125 | C |
| 125 | N |

I want to see this instead as

| Agreement ID | ProductStatus |
| --- | --- |
| 125 | A,C, N |

OR

| Agreement ID | ProductStatus1 | ProductStatus2 | ProductStatus3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | A | C | N |

I've tried a few simple pivots, but the values a, c & n CAN be different and random values each time.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? What version?

Comment: What version of SQL technology are you using?  MSSQL, MYSQL, other?

Comment: Ah yes should have mentioned that - SSMS 15

Answer (score 0):

You can use a group_concat function. Your query will be something like this

```
SELECT agreement_id, group_concat(Product_Status)
FrOM mytable
group by agreement_id
```

This is for MySQL, for other databases you can search for group_concat alternative function for that particular database.
Seems like you are new to database. You can use this reference to learn more.
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/basic-mysql-tutorial.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you can get three values in different columns using conditional aggregation:

```
select agreementid,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then ProductStatus end) as ProductStatus_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then ProductStatus end) as ProductStatus_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then ProductStatus end) as ProductStatus_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by agreementid order by agreementid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by agreementid;
```

The SQL standard for creating a list is:

```
select agreementid,
       list_agg(ProductStatus, ',') within group (order by productstatus) as productstatuses
from t
group by agreementid;
```

Many databases have different names for this function.

In both of these cases, the ordering of the columns or elements of the list are indeterminate.  SQL table represent *unordered* sets (well, technically multisets) so there is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.